Create new column based on comparing last two rows for a specific order ID in a kdb+ table
There is a table that exists with many entries for unique orderIDs, (i.e. unique orderID 123 can have N number of entries). I wanted to compare the last 2 entries for each unique orderID that I have, and add a new column to my result set based on conditions that return true when the values are compared between each of the 2 entries for each orderID.
How can I do this? Here is what I tried so far but keep running into length errors with the second line of code:
myResult:select from myTable where ({x in -2#x;i) fby orderID; / this works by getting the last 2 entries for each unique orderID

/ trying to check if the second row's myType is a certain value, and if my first entry for myValue is equal to "0", and if the start time of my second row - the end time of my previous row is greater than a certain number of seconds
update didEventHappen:?[(next[myType] in `TYPE_A) and (myValue="0") and ((next[start.time] - end.time) > 00:00:01.000); 1b; 0b] fby orderID from myResult 


Providing a sample input table and expected output would help

Hard to know without a data sample but it looks to me like your issues might be:

For an update statement you don't use fby, you use by. You use fby in where clauses.

Is your myValue column a type char ("c") or type string ("C")? If it's string then your equality won't quite work but a raze can avoid the ambiguity.


So this should work (ignoring the timestamp clause for now, you can add that in):
myTable:([]orderID:100?til 10;myType:100?`TYPE_A`TYPE_B;myvalue:string 100?til 5)

myResult:select from myTable where ({x in -2#x};i) fby orderID;

q)update didEventHappen:?[(next[myType] in `TYPE_A) and raze[myvalue="0"];1b;0b] by orderID from myResult
orderID myType myvalue didEventHappen
-------------------------------------
8       TYPE_B ,"4"    0
3       TYPE_A ,"3"    0
8       TYPE_A ,"4"    0
3       TYPE_B ,"4"    0
1       TYPE_B ,"1"    0
7       TYPE_B ,"2"    0
7       TYPE_B ,"4"    0
2       TYPE_B ,"2"    0
5       TYPE_A ,"1"    0
9       TYPE_B ,"2"    0
2       TYPE_B ,"4"    0
9       TYPE_A ,"1"    0
4       TYPE_A ,"1"    0
0       TYPE_A ,"1"    0
4       TYPE_A ,"0"    0
5       TYPE_A ,"3"    0
6       TYPE_B ,"0"    1
6       TYPE_A ,"0"    0
0       TYPE_B ,"2"    0
1       TYPE_A ,"3"    0


You're right, as soon as I switched to by, it worked perfectly. Thanks @terrylynch

Please provide small a small sample table and expected output to make answering questions easier.
Sample table roughly based on description:
q)myTable:([] orderID:1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3;
 myType:`TYPE_A`TYPE_A`TYPE_A`TYPE_B`TYPE_B`TYPE_A`TYPE_B`TYPE_B`TYPE_B;
 start:(.z.d+00:00:30.000)+(2*til 9)*0D00:00:01;
 end:.z.d+9#00:00:35.000;
 myValue:9#"0";
 xmyValue:9#"0")
q)myTable
orderID myType start                         end                           myValue xmyValue
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:30.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
1       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:32.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
1       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:34.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
2       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:36.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
2       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:38.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
2       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:40.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
3       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:42.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
3       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:44.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0
3       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:46.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0

Query:
q)update didEventHappen:i={
    c:count x;
    $[all (last[x`myType]=`TYPE_A;
          (x[c-2]`xmyValue)="0";
          ((`time$last x`start) - `time$x[c-2]`end) > 00:00:01.000);
      x[c-2]`r;
      -1]}([] myType;xmyValue;start;end;r:i)
    by orderID from myTable
orderID myType start                         end                           myValue xmyValue didEventHappen
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:30.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0
1       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:32.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0
1       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:34.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0
2       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:36.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0
2       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:38.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        1
2       TYPE_A 2024.10.18D00:00:40.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0
3       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:42.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0
3       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:44.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0
3       TYPE_B 2024.10.18D00:00:46.000000000 2024.10.18D00:00:35.000000000 0       0        0

